# Ionic Android navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition not worked in Android Kitkat 4.4.4

Tags: gps, ionic-framework, android-4.4-kitkat

I build an android Ionic app that using navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition, here is my code :

```
var opsi = {maxAge: 30000, frequency : 30000, enableHighAccuracy: false};

  function success (pos) {
    var lat1 = pos.coords.latitude;
    var long1 = pos.coords.longitude;
    $http.post(link, {
      devicetime : getdtNow(),
      token : token, 
      longlat : {
      lat: lat1,
      long: long1,        
      },
      searchTerm : ''
      }).success(function (res){
          $ionicLoading.hide();
          var s = JSON.stringify(res);
          var reply = JSON.parse(s);
          if (reply.result == 'OK'){
              parkingsites = reply.parkingsites;
              if (maplistview==0){
                gmap($scope,$location);  
                getparkimage($scope);
              }
              else if (maplistview==1){
                getparkimage($scope);
              }
          }
          else if(reply.result == 'TOKENNOTFOUND'){
            state='templates/loginregister.html';
            ct_state = 'loginregister';
            $location.path('/');
            $ionicPopup.alert({
              title: 'App Warning',
              template: 'Sesi Anda Telah Habis'
            });
          }
          else {

          }
      }).error(function (data) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: 'App Warning',
          template: 'Koneksi Ke Server Bermasalah'
        });
      });
  };

  function error(err) {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: 'App Warning',
      template: err.message
    });
    //console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
  };

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, opsi);
```

When I try my app in android devices with all OS except Kitkat 4.4.4, that code is working well, but when I try in Android 4.4.4, it always called function error, with message time out expired, anybody can help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this working on android 4.4.4 by just using the following code:

```
function getUserPosition () {
       var positionOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
       return $ionicPlatform.ready()
        .then(function () {
          return $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(positionOptions);
        }, function (error) {
          console.error("Error getting user position: " + angular.toJson(error));
        });
     }
```

I am using the [cordova geolocation plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/).

Cordova version: 5.4.1, ionic framework version: 1.2.1, ionic cli version: 1.7.12.

Comment: what exactly have you tried? I have the code I posted currently working on a Sony Xperia E running the stock rom version 4.4.4 kitkat. What device are you using? Did you give the app permissions to use location services?

Comment: my device is Polytron 4G450 Kitkat 4.4.4, I have called $ionicPlatform.ready() before called getcurrentlocation, and it doesn't work, is some device with android 4.4.4 really can't getcurrentlocation ?

Comment: The android version shouldn't be the problem, and your device is running a snapdragon SoC, so the hardware also supports the necessary features. My guess is either the device you own is either malfunctioning, has the location services option turned off or the application was denied access to location information.

Comment: by the way I still use  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition, not $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition, because I think both of that is same, I ever try using $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition, but when declare 'ngCordova' in angular module, this error always show : Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngCordova due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngCordova' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.

Comment: How are you importing ngCordoda? the ngCordova import in your index.html fime should come before (above) the ```cordova.js``` itself. On your module, the order doesn't matter, but add it after ionic. Also make sure the path to your ```ng-cordova.min.js``` file is correct.